# Set display text of 'Add'-Dropdown-Button in CollectionEditor

Tags: c#, .net, uitypeeditor

How can I set the display text of a add button's dropdown menu in my custom CollectionEditor?

[image]

The dropdown menu shows the Type-Array I return in my custom CollectionEditor.
But I don't want the user to see the class names. I want to display a meaningful text for the user.
I would be very thankful for your help!

Comment: could you please share your object class that you are binding with dropdown

Comment: My object class is very simple. Nothing special about it. I also tried it with some other classes, because I have multiple generic lists I want to configure using the UITypeEditor (CollectionEditor). The CollectionEditor always shows the class name.

Comment: please share the code snippet, how you are bind your dropdown.

Comment: I bind the classes in my custom CollectionEditor by overriding _Type[] CreateNewItemTypes()_. `public class ActionCollectionEditor : CollectionEditor
      {
         private Type[] types;

         public ActionCollectionEditor(Type type) : base(type)
         {
            types = new Type[] { typeof(ExportAction), typeof(MinStockViolationsAction), typeof(StoragePlaceAssignmentAction) };
         }

         protected override Type[] CreateNewItemTypes()
         {
            return types;
         }
      }`

Comment: ...DropdownMenu shows three items: ExportAction, MinStockViolationsAction and StoragePlaceAssignmentAction.

Comment: and also share MinStockViolationsAction,StoragePlaceAssignmentAction,ExportAction

Comment: I cannot put the whole classes in a comment and I cannot link you to the source code. But as I mentioned - there is nothing special about these classes. I just need to know, how I can tell the CollectionEditor to use a specific string instead of the Type.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know there are two methods to manipulate text in the Add button.

1- Creating a TypeDelegate: [How to customize names in "Add" button dropdown in the PropertyGrid custom collection editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36385305/how-to-customize-names-in-add-button-dropdown-in-the-propertygrid-custom-colle)

2- Hooking into CollectionForm's Controls (Ugly, Not Recommended, but an alternative)

```
 public sealed class OutputItemEditor : CollectionEditor // need a reference to System.Design.dll
{
    public OutputItemEditor(Type type)
        : base(type)
    {
    }

    protected override Type[] CreateNewItemTypes()
    {
        return new[] { typeof(StaticOutputItem), typeof(VariableOutputItem),typeof(ExpressionOutputItem) };
    }

    protected override CollectionForm CreateCollectionForm()
    {
        CollectionForm collectionForm = base.CreateCollectionForm();            
        collectionForm.Text = "Output Collection";

        //Modify the Add Item Button Text
        try
        {
            //You can use "collectionForm.Controls.Find("addButton",true)" here also
            foreach (ToolStripItem item in collectionForm.Controls[0].Controls[1].Controls[0].ContextMenuStrip.Items)
            {
                //Since Item Names are the Type Names
                switch (item.Text)
                {
                    case "StaticOutputItem":
                        item.Text = "Static Output Item";
                        break;
                    case "VariableOutputItem":
                        item.Text = "Variable Output Item";
                        break;
                    case "ExpressionOutputItem":
                        item.Text = "Expression Output Item";
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }

        return collectionForm;
    }
}
```