# How to customize names in "Add" button dropdown in the PropertyGrid custom collection editor

Tags: c#, editor, propertygrid

I'm using **PropertyGrid** to edit a collection. An object with the collection is defined as following:

```
class ObjWithCollection
{
    [Editor(typeof(MyCustomCollectionEditor),typeof(UITypeEditor))]
    public List<ItemBase> collection { get; set; } = new List<ItemBase>();//ItemBase is abstract
}
```

The collection contains the objects of two types, derived from **ItemBase** class: **Item1** and **Item2**. These classes defined as following:

```
public abstract class ItemBase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ItemBase() { }
    public ItemBase(string name) { Name = name; }
}

public class Item1:ItemBase
{
    public Item1():base("Item 1 name"){}
}

[DisplayName("item2 test display name")]
public class Item2:ItemBase
{
    public Item2() : base("item 2 name") { }
}
```

To be able to add new items to the collection via the editor, I also defined the custom collection editor class and override **CreateNewItemTypes** to list all types suitable for collection:

```
class MyCustomCollectionEditor : CollectionEditor
{
    public MyCustomCollectionEditor(Type type) : base(type){}
    protected override Type[] CreateNewItemTypes()
    {
        return new Type[] { typeof(Item1), typeof(Item2) };
    }
}
```

Then I bind my custom editor to the **ObjWithCollection.collection** property with **Editor** attibute (see **ObjWithCollection.collection** definition).

This works fine and I able to edit my collection, including the adding of the new items. The Add button has a dropdown which allows user to select the type of element to add.
[editor window http://i.share.pho.to/31d50d09_o.png](http://i.share.pho.to/31d50d09_o.png)

But in the Add button dropdown the items called "**Item1**" and "**Item2**" and I can't change this names. I tried **DisplayName** attribute, **ToString** override, but no luck.

So, **the qustion is** how to I can output the custom names for the elements of the **Add** button menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is possible directly from the property grid's code. However, you can use a [TypeDelegator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.typedelegator.aspx) to trick the system and force it to use for example your DisplayName attribute in lieu of the type's Name property it uses by default.

1) create a custom TypeDelegator, like this:

```
class MyTypeDelegator : TypeDelegator
{
    public MyTypeDelegator(Type delegatingType)
        : base(delegatingType)
    {
    }

    public override string Name
    {
        get
        {
            var dna = (DisplayNameAttribute)typeImpl.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(DisplayNameAttribute));
            return dna != null ? dna.DisplayName : typeImpl.Name;
        }
    }
}
```

2) modify CreateNewItemTypes() like this:

```
    protected override Type[] CreateNewItemTypes()
    {
        return new Type[] { new MyTypeDelegator(typeof(Item1)), new MyTypeDelegator(typeof(Item2)) };
    }
```

Now, you should see the display names instead of the name in the menu.

Answer (score 0):

You can also change the text by hooking into CollectionForm's Controls (Ugly, Not Recommended, DO NOT USE IN PRODUCTION, Note that it could be changed and obsolete in anytime)

```
 public sealed class OutputItemEditor : CollectionEditor // need a reference to System.Design.dll
{
    public OutputItemEditor(Type type)
        : base(type)
    {
    }

    protected override Type[] CreateNewItemTypes()
    {
        return new[] { typeof(StaticOutputItem), typeof(VariableOutputItem),typeof(ExpressionOutputItem) };
    }

    protected override CollectionForm CreateCollectionForm()
    {
        CollectionForm collectionForm = base.CreateCollectionForm();            
        collectionForm.Text = "Output Collection";

        //Modify the Add Item Button Text
        try
        {
            //You can use "collectionForm.Controls.Find("addButton",true)" here also
            foreach (ToolStripItem item in collectionForm.Controls[0].Controls[1].Controls[0].ContextMenuStrip.Items)
            {
                //Since Item Names are the Type Names
                switch (item.Text)
                {
                    case "StaticOutputItem":
                        item.Text = "Static Output Item";
                        break;
                    case "VariableOutputItem":
                        item.Text = "Variable Output Item";
                        break;
                    case "ExpressionOutputItem":
                        item.Text = "Expression Output Item";
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }

        return collectionForm;
    }
}
```